# Filter ids with having count > 1 in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to filter lines of data frames by ids having only one level of a variable.

For example :

```
dt <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), 
                 x = c("x", "x", "x", "y"))

setDT(dt)

   id x
1:  a x
2:  a x
3:  b x
4:  b y
```

Here, the id b have 2 different level of variable x. I would like to remove lines of id "b", so the result would be :

```
   id x
1:  a x
2:  a x
```

I can do it using `uniqueN` and then joining and filtering, but it seems slow for larger datasets.

```
dt[ , list(count = uniqueN(x)), by = id][dt, on = "id"][count == 1L, names(dt), with = FALSE]
```

What is the straight/efficient or smarter way to do this in `data.table` please ?

Thanks

Comment: Indeed @Maximus, my bad I used the wrong terms to browse my question, your solution is nice ! ~25 secs for 7M rows

Comment: How long this runs `setkey(dt, id) ; indx <- unique(dt)[, .N < 2, by = id][(V1), id] ; dt[.(indx)]` ?

Comment: Hello, it runs really faster but it doesn't work the same way as Maximus's solution and don't provide the expected result

Comment: Probably because you have more columns than just two. Try changing `unique(dt)` to `unique(dt, by = c("id", "x"))`